# layout_marginLeft works as right on Android API < 11 when View in FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-framelayout

When I use `layout_marginLeft` or set left margin from code it works as `layout_marginRight`. This behavior was seen when I placed `View` with `layout_marginLeft` in `FrameLayout` or in a root of a layout on Android API < 11.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:background="#77cc99"
        >
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:background="#eebbaa">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello World, MyActivity"
                />
        </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 7):

By default `android:layout_gravity` attribute set to "left" for `FrameLayout`. If you want to use `android:layout_marginLeft` you should change it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:background="#77cc99"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:background="#eebbaa" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World, MyActivity" />    
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: i love this answer :D, thx you saved me (i already wasted 1 day)